# TinyMce 4 clears my code tags after saved in database

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using **TinyMCE 4** to edit a textarea . i'm using **code sample plugin**  .

After the saving  all `textarea` in **database**  i can't see codes like `<html>` `<body>`  `<?php ?>` .

When i load saved data in fronend of my website like a article everything is good But when i want to edit article inside `textarea` **TinyMce** clears  all my `codes` and `tags` .

How i can load all contents of my article from **database** without losing `codes` and `tags` inside a **textarea** to edit and save ?

It seams **TinyMce** remove all tags before loading  maybe for security problems !

I'm using **TinyMce** by **Codeigniter** PHP framework

Before Save in db : 
[image]

After Saving in db and reload : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by adding :

```
<?php echo htmlentities($data); ?>
```

**$data** is data loaded to `textarea` and `htmlentities()` makes tags visible